# MATLAB Loop to Randomly Modify String Characters

Tags: regex, string, matlab, random

I’ve started programming in MATLAB recently and tried implementing a 1337 speaker-like generator/string manipulator just for fun. As a challenge, I’m trying to randomly change the occurrence of each character so that not all “a” are changed to “@“.

It appears that my attempt works to some extend since it's very arbitrary (yet sometimes ineffective), but I believe there’s a better way of accomplishing this. Perhaps to add more alternatives for each of the 26 characters and randomly select from them, respectively?

```
function O = obfuscate(s)

str = 'hello world';

for i=1:length(str)
    randomNum = randi(26,1);

    switch randomNum
        case 1            
            str = regexprep(str, 'a', '@', 'once');
        case 2
            str = regexprep(str, 'b', 'l3', 'once');
        case 3
            str = regexprep(str, 'c', '<', 'once');
        case 4
            str = regexprep(str, 'd', '|]', 'once');
        case 5
            str = regexprep(str, 'e', '3', 'once');
        case 6
            str = regexprep(str, 'f', '|#', 'once');
        case 7
            str = regexprep(str, 'g', '6', 'once');
        case 8
            str = regexprep(str, 'h', '|-|', 'once');
        case 9
            str = regexprep(str, 'i', '!', 'once');
        case 10
            str = regexprep(str, 'j', '_/', 'once');
        case 11
            str = regexprep(str, 'k', '|{', 'once');
        case 12
            str = regexprep(str, 'l', '1', 'once');
        case 13
            str = regexprep(str, 'm', '|\/|', 'once');
        case 14
            str = regexprep(str, 'n', '/\/', 'once');
        case 15
            str = regexprep(str, 'o', '[]', 'once');
        case 16
            str = regexprep(str, 'p', '|*', 'once');
        case 17
            str = regexprep(str, 'q', '9', 'once');
        case 18
            str = regexprep(str, 'r', '|2', 'once');
        case 19
            str = regexprep(str, 's', '$', 'once');
        case 20
            str = regexprep(str, 't', '+', 'once');
        case 21
            str = regexprep(str, 'u', '|_|', 'once');
        case 22 
            str = regexprep(str, 'v', '\/', 'once');
        case 23
            str = regexprep(str, 'w', '\X/', 'once');
        case 24
            str = regexprep(str, 'x', '%', 'once');
        case 25
            str = regexprep(str, 'y', '¥', 'once');
        case 26
            str = regexprep(str, 'z', '2', 'once');
    end

   O = str;

    %fprintf('%s(%i)', str(i), randomNum);  
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand how you are deciding to choose the replacements?  Can you show us simple input and expected output here?

Comment: Sure. I've hardcoded this function to use `str = 'hello world'` but you could change that to `str = s` to accept arguments when you run obfuscate('your text here'). As requested, running this function for 'hello world' can yield different results since it's random. One possible result is: `|-|3llo w[]rld `

Comment: `so that not all “a” are changed to “@“` ... OK but how does 'hello world' have anything to do with "not all a" ?

Comment: My apologies. It was a generic example. I should've said not all "e" are changed to "3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a random number between 1 and 26 but only whilst looping through the string. In your example you would only generate 11 random numbers so it is possible to never get an obfuscation whilst looping through the string.

This explains why it would be 'sometimes ineffective' as you described.

For example, in one case your random number generator could generate 10 2's in a row which would only ever change the character 'b'.

You don't have any b's in your example so none of the text will be obfuscated.

You might have more success using a map container (search for containers.map in the Matlab help) to map each character to an obfuscation (to replace your switch case logic) instead of leaving this up to probability.

You could then generate a uniform random number between e.g. 1 and 2 in each loop iteration to determine whether the character should be obfuscated.

**Example:**

```
function O = obfuscate(s)

str = 'hello world';
keys ={'h','e','l','o','w','r','d'};
values = {'|-|','3','1','[]','\X/','|2','|]'};
obfuscationMap = containers.Map(keys,values);
tempCell = {}  %cell to hold the growing string

for i = 1:length(str)
    randomNum = randi(2,1);
    switch randomNum
        case(1) %obfuscate
            if(isKey(obfuscationMap, str(i)) %check key is in map to avoid missing chars
                tempCell{end+1} = obfuscationMap(str(i));
            else
                tempCell{end+1} = str(i);
            end
        case(2) %don't obfuscate
            tempCell{end+1} = str(i);
    end
end

O = strjoin(tempStr,''); %combine cell in single string without spaces
```

With the above code, when randomNum is a 1, you'll get an obfuscation, if randomNum is a 2 then you won't.

So you should get obfuscations a bit more often than you were seeing previously.

You may need to modify a bit to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Excellent answer! I did not know it could be achieved this way although your suggestion is way out of my scope as a novice user of Matlab. Any more suggestions, or perhaps a simple example I can analyze, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (with some more tweaking). Incredible! You've taught me something new and I'm very greatful. I look forward to use mappings more often! Thank you so much, James.